# Grenade that makes you see all black (opposite of flashbangs)

Tags: weapons

Can flashbangs in real life make you see all black for a few seconds instead of all white?

I'm making a videogame and I want to know if it's possible to have flashbangs that are already available in real life or if I need to use magic for that one.

Just like a real life flashbang, it has to be a stun weapon, non-lethal and preferably no life-threatening permanent damage.

I know for a fact that when I get low blood pressure, I see all black and go momentarily blind and feel my ears ringing, especially when lifting in the gym on an empty stomach.

So seeing all black instead of all white isn't just a personal design choice as to not blind or give an epileptic attack to myself or to my players every time someone throws a grenade... but it's also technically possible.

Can an actual grenade give you those same symptoms?

Comment: The title implies "unconsciousness" to me, but the question appears to imply just greying out.  Which is the intended result?  (Also, you should probably stop lifting in the gym on an empty stomach, just saying.)

Comment: I have seen stun grenades in various computer games and just assumed they exist in the real world as well.

Comment: Probably shouldn't hold heavy weights if you're close to passing out.

Comment: @pipe it doesn't happen slowly or gradually enough to predict that it's about to happen, it's more like finishing a set of deadlifts and on the last 2 repetitions things go black, ears ring and nausea hits and knees go weak. it's like a 20% chance of this happening on any heavy set if I skipped breakfast, a minor debuff.

Comment: There is no such thing as a non-lethal weapon. At best, there are **less**-lethal weapons. Tossing a flash-bang grenade is not at all risk-free.

Comment: @AlexP then I'm content with a normal level of lethality of a normal white flashbang.... but black

Comment: Then what's wrong with an ordinary high-power flash lamp? It does have a risk of permanent vision damage, but if the light is just very bright with little in the way of infrared or ultraviolet the risk is not *very* great, and temporary blindness is guaranteed. In fact, even an ordinary flash-bang grenade should work; they don't make the targets see white, they make the targets not see period.

Comment: re: the gym, if that happens stop your set don't continue. It sounds like your both holding your breath and tensing too hard triggering a low pressure reflex. Feeling light headed after a set happens from the sudden change in pressure from putting the weight down too quickly. Just remember to breath both before and _during_ an exercise, you shouldn't be losing your vision during reps, full or empty stomach

Comment: If you want something fun and different, but flashbang-like, how about a high powered erratic strobe light with matching goggles.  The goggles dim at just the right time so that the wearers just see a normal dim room, but the bright light dazzles and disorients anyone else.  You could match this with a ridculously loud acoustic devise and canceling earbuds.

Comment: @AlexP There isn't in the sense those weapons occasionally kill people, but there is in the sense less-lethal weapons are often called or sold as "non-lethal". Even "less-lethal" is giving the benefit of the doubt that those weapons aren't fired widely with the conviction that you can't kill someone with something not designed to explicitly kill.

Comment: So, Peruvian Instant Darkness Powder?

Comment: Don't flash-bangs and their like work by over-loading the optic nerves? Doesn't low blood pressure work by cutting off any stimuli? At the end of the day, write a good bang-flash and the reader will swallow it… but why? How would the victim be any better or worse off seeing 'all black' than 'all white'?

Answer (score 26):

> Can flashbangs in real life make you see all black for a few seconds instead of all white?

A smoke bomb will do. You can choose any color and the people caught within the smoke will only see that color. Takes longer than a flashbang to take effect but is actually less harmful. Not only there is less chance of killing an epileptic person, you also don't harm anyone's retinas.

It's also legal in many jurisdictions, even for civillian use. Here is a link to some black smoke bombs should you wish to experiment with one for inspiration or science!

https://enolagaye.com/colored-smoke/black/

And look at what they say about this product:

> Gone are the days of burning toxic tires to produce the visual effect of black smoke. Developed over the span of a few years, our non-toxic black smoke uses only the highest quality dye to replicate the look of a real fire. Fitted with our easy to use Wire Pull® ignition system, you have the perfect black smoke effect option.

And at the parent page to that:

> We consider these products to be perfectly safe for general consumer use and this category has been specifically designed with everyday consumers in mind.

(By the way I find it funny that we live in a world where the everyday consumer needs smoke bombs)

That thing even comes in different venting and density options, so you can pick one that suits your needs.

Oh and if you want people to actually faint as per the title, rather than just being caught in darkness and confused, add odors to it. [The Pentagon has been actively researching that for decades](https://www.eurekalert.org/news-releases/714884) (emphasis below are mine):

> (...) But Dalton did find two loathsome odours that transcend culture. One is a truly repugnant mixture called **US Government Standard Bathroom Malodor**, a stink concocted to test the efficiency of deodorant cleaning products. "It's very pungent," says Dalton. "More precisely, it smells like sh*t, but much, much stronger. **It fills your head. It gets to you in ways that are unimaginable. It's not something you are likely to come across in the real world.**"
>
> The smell is so awful that some volunteers began to scream and curse after just a few seconds' exposure. Even though the smell is quite harmless, **almost everyone thought it would damage their health**. Dalton wasn't surprised.

Just amp the concentration until it makes people faint.

Comment: This doesn't fulfill OP's condition, that it's a flashbang (instantaneous).

Comment: @Dor1000 the condigions, as per OP are: *"it has to be a stun weapon, non-lethal and preferably no life-threatening permanent damage."*. Nothing about being instantaneous.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming unconsciousness is potentially okay, though if someone is rendered unconscious while standing it might violate the "no life-threatening injuries" rule.  There really aren't any non-lethal incapacitants, just *less* lethal.  That said...

#### Halothane Grenade

[Halothane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halothane) is a potent anesthetic, heavier than air (which means it won't dissipate *too* fast to be effective as a thrown weapon) and is a liquid at STP.  Using either an explosive or mechanical aerosolizer, your grenade can disperse it around the point of impact.

Minimal doses would cause reduced level-of-consciousness without fully rendering the target unconscious, while someone who gets a lungful would likely be knocked right out.  As with anything that induces unconsciousness, there is a risk of permanent damage, but as mentioned in the precis, there's no such thing as a non-lethal weapon that can actually incapacitate a person.

On the minus side, it's also a potent ozone antagonist, so anyone using it isn't going to be very eco-conscious in doing so.

Answer (score 8):

Tear Gas:

[KU Gas in the Great War](https://www.kumc.edu/school-of-medicine/academics/departments/history-and-philosophy-of-medicine/archives/wwi/essays/medicine/gas-in-the-great-war.html)

"Several chemicals were weaponized in WWI and France actually was the first to use gas - they deployed tear gas in August 1914. The agent used was either xylyl bromide, which is described as smelling ‘pleasant and aromatic’, or ethyl bromoacetate, described as ‘fruity and pungent.’ Both are colorless liquids and have to be atomized to be dispersed as weapons. As lachrymatory agents, they irritate the eyes and cause uncontrolled tearing. Large doses can cause temporary blindness. If inhaled they also make breathing difficult. Symptoms usually resolve by 30 minutes after contact. Thus, tear gas was never very effective as a weapon against groups of enemy soldiers."

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the metal casing of a Grenade (say, wrapped in soft Plastic) - just the blast wave alone (without any shrapnel) would be enough to cause a bTBI (Blast-induced, Traumatic Brain Injury) and knock someone unconscious.

However as others have pointed out - if you have enough force/energy/effect on target to render someone unconscious, you probably have enough that with the right (or wrong, depending on PoV) set of circumstances, you could have a lethal effect.

Comment: *less than* lethal; YMMV. +1. You can't pop smoke and then breach into a building with kids or the infirm in it, let alone use tear gas or flash bangs, or w/e this, *not-guaranteed*-to-be-lethal weapon is.

Answer (score 3):

**Vantablack smoke grenade**

Flashbangs are white because they emit a bunch of light.

Black is the opposite of white, it's the absence of light. Thus there's no such thing as black light (not to be confused with *blacklight*, which is ultraviolet and mostly non-visible). We perceive black, mostly because "black" objects around us are actually very dark grey but still reflect an appreciable amount of light.

There are materials that reflect a negligible amount of light, which include [Super Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_black) and the perhaps better known [Vantablack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack). Objects coated in such materials appear flat, even when full of wrinkles.

You could imagine a grenade that releases a puff of a black powder material that absorbs near 100% of light, giving the illusion of a black explosion. That alone of course wouldn't blind you, it would juste create a space of black void in the air that you can simply look away from.

However, there's a good chance the powder would also cause eye irration (and possibly blindness) and be wildly unsafe to breathe (which might cause all sorts of other fun effects, or simply HP damage-over-time), so that might do the trick.

While not quite a "black flashbang", I offer this because I think it would be visually interesting, and still would make a serviceable weapon in a game.

Comment: Using a pressurised gas to disperse it might be a way to eliminate the flash of an explosive propellant.  An electrically heated wire that is wrapped around a plastic pressure vessel that contains the powder and gas and ruptures where it is weakenned.
.

Answer (score 1):

Your title says grenade, yet you talk of flashbang.

This answer is about what a person see when near a strong concussion wave (grenade, flashbang):

Despite sensory overload caused by loudness and shockwave pelting against your ears and body, your cochlear balance is also overly simulated to a point of disorientation, we will focus on what the eyes see because the video games does not offer audiotory-overload nor strong olfactory simulation.

**White - mostly**

For the eyeballs subjected to a flash-bang, the visual aftereffect is much on the white side and none of the blackish aspect.

When I say more white-ish, it actually a strong white with a start of gradual diffusion toward to a light shade of yellow around the edge of your eyeballs’ field of vision.

Much like the after effect of staring into the Sun then closing your eyeballs and seeing those tiny dots of glow, flashbang is like being inside the Sun, your entiree eyeball retina surface area are impacted with the surrounding edge of field vision starting to recover from strong white, to faint yellow down to restoration of actual colorized recpetion.  The area of white is not really shrinking during recovery because unlike the self-inflicted Sun spot, it got bathed inside the sun.  Recovery of vision restoration starts around the edge of your field of vision (because blood circulation starts there (more so on the sides, than on top or bottom.)

This whiteness-diffused-to-yellowish-edge gets smaller and smaller over time but it is like a S-curve of recovery, you get most of your vision back (survival gene) and a reminder (long time big-spot).

**Black - most severe**

The only time it goes to black is when the concussion bang becomes too strong to a point of an eye retinal detachment or the eyeball blood vessels collapsed/blocked/stroked and blackness is in either top part of field of vision or lower part, or in spots (as in a slow-going macular disease).  Those blackness have poor recovery time, if at all, more permanent than not (unless treated promptly).

**Red - rarely**

Other rarity is redness in field of vision that occurs when the eye balls have broken retinal blood vessel and that red blood fills the internal of the eyeballs.  Typically that smearness of red tint is even and subtle but not pronounced.

**Disclaimer**

This answer is not meant to be a medical diagnosis guide and are provided for gaming purpose, strictly and only.  As it goes without saying, go to the emergency room if you experience ANY of above.

Comment: "no life-threatening permanent damage" ... checks out, +1. I thought tripping over my high heels was cool; (*you are suffering from*) **Detached retina** 'be one helluva game mechanic.

Comment: @Mazura Now I want to see the in-game animation for retinal reattachment.

Comment: Should be interesting if parts of the view field remains blacked out during gameplay until ones safely arrival at and attended to by such an advanced recovery station.